# It's possible to redirect specific domain trafic to a secondary local IP?

Tags: php, raspberry-pi, xampp

My family company has a webpage runing under a Xampp server. I'm trying to host my own server with its own webpage(local). I want to redirect all incoming traffic to the main server to my RPi when it comes using my domain name.

This is the closest attempt I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com [OR, NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http\:\/\/192.168.1.98\/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it only works on local and it's changing the browser displayed URL. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Because XAMPP is using Apache webserver, you can configure a [reverse proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html) in Apache that sends all traffic on *mydomain.com* to your Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

Finally seems I achieved the goal with this modifying the httpd.conf, this page guided me: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension

```
#Enable bunch of modules for mod_proxy and submodules as described in this page:
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so


#This block redirects only those request using the domain 
# mydomain.com or www.mydomain.com
<VirtualHost *:*>
  # Servers to proxy the connection, or;
  # List of application servers:
  # Usage:
  # ProxyPass / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
  # ProxyPassReverse / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
  # Example:

  ServerName  mydomain.com
  ServerAlias www.mydomain.com

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.98/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.98/
</VirtualHost>

#This first block redirects any other request
<VirtualHost *:*>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
</VirtualHost>
```